# Powershell Remoting in For my AD Account Alone

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2

I am pretty new to ServerFault and apologize if I am following any of the processes incorrectly in any way....

I have only worked a little with the basics of Powershell. I am looking for a secure way to remote into my computers on the domain. I would like to set it up to where only my AD account can remote-into other computers on the domain using Powershell, but other computers are not able to do so.

I am trying to remote-in, so that I can begin installing software remotely. I would like to be able to install the software on all computers in a certain OU when the computer is on. What steps should I take to make both of these things occur?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The default PSSessionConfiguration has these permissions.  If you don't put any other users in the these groups, or any group that are within those groups they will not have access.

```
PS > (Get-PSSessionConfiguration -Name Microsoft.PowerShell).Permission

NT AUTHORITY\INTERACTIVE AccessAllowed, BUILTIN\Administrators AccessAllowed,
BUILTIN\Remote Management Users AccessAllowed
```

You can add your account to one of these groups, or you could create an publish a new session configuration with a different ACL.  IMO It isn't a good idea to change the ACLs on the default session configuration.

Basically this means the default is that only 'Adminitrators', and 'Domain Administrators' have remote access.